# Voltage divider circuit for DC voltage measurement with protection against AC voltage?

Tags: dc, voltage-divider, voltage-measurement, voltmeter

Need some help with making a simple voltage divider to sense DC voltage of 0-30 V range with my DAQ which accepts 0-10 V analog input.

I was wondering if the input voltage is by mistake an AC voltage, what would be the reading on the DAQ? Will there be any risk to the DAQ? And how can I rectify the AC voltage without a bridge rectifier (just for protecting the DAQ and prevent AC voltage input from damaging my DAQ)?

[image]

DAQ like USB-6009.
[image]

Comment: Can you add some more information about the DAQ? What is the model number?

Comment: For example the NI USB-6009.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For AC voltages, the DAQ would continue measuring, and you would see the AC waveform coming through in the data (assuming that the sample rate is high enough to measure it).

An AC voltage itself will not cause damage, assuming that the voltages are still within the ratings of your DAQ. You've expressed that the voltage range of your DAQ is 0-10V. Therefore it can handle any AC *or* DC signal that remains in that range.

If you applied directly to the DAQ a 1v amplitude AC voltage with a DC offset of 0v, the range of the AC would be -1v to +1v. This would be outside the range for your DAQ for the negative half of the waveform. But if you had a 1v amplitude AC voltage with a DC offset of 5v, then now the range is (+4v to +6v), so the voltage is always staying within the range.

So with your divider you can already handle any AC waveform that stays within the 0v-30v range,

Note: If you are using the USB-6009, then this system *can* measure negative voltages, and actually can go from -10v to +10v.

Comment: thank you for the great answer..
Yes the voltage AC or DC won't be more than 30V. I understood my circuit will work but I was wondering if there are any unnecessary components in the circuit that can be eliminated.

Comment: Are you using the USB-6009 or just something similar?

Comment: something similar but much lower speed, like data logger.

Comment: Are you using the Zener to clamp the voltage to prevent an over voltage? You can check the specs of your data logger and if it has over voltage protection built in to a sufficient voltage then you can remove the zener. Also I would recommend checking the input resistance of the logger, as if it is a similar value to 100k you will have a voltage divider affect with the 100k resistor and you will end up with a smaller signal than you expect.

Comment: yes I added the Zener exactly like that, I also added the specs of DAQ.

Comment: Looks like there isn't any over voltage protection, so you will need to keep the Zener. Although the specs seem to imply you can use an input voltage of 32v? Are you sure you need the divider? Also why do you have the 100k resistor? Is it for current limiting?

Comment: The working voltage is for the power of the module. The Analog input is 0-10v.
The 100K resistor used to provide some method of decay or discharge.

Comment: You wont need the 100k, there's no need to provide a decay or discharge for the capacitor as it is only for smoothing.

Comment: ok thank you again..
No need for that resistor, how about the value of the capacitor, and is it ok for it to be unpolarized?